# Keeping Character Types/Names in xts object in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, xts

Okay so this is probably a really dumb question, but I've check around and couldn't find anything on it so I thought I'd ask here. I'm looking at stock prices for a range of different stocks and I would like to use the `xts` package, but the problem is that `xts` removes names/character data types from datasets, such that a dataframe such as this:

```
TIME     | STOCK  |   PRICE
-----------------------------
.....    | QQQQ   |   .....
.....    | WWWW   |   .....
.....    | EEEE   |   .....
```

gets converted into an `xts` object, the `STOCK` column gets removed so that the `xts` object now looks like this:

```
 TIME    |   PRICE
--------------------
 .....   |   .....
 .....   |   .....
 .....   |   .....
```

What's a good way for R to keep track of the names of the stock for each time and price if I am using `xts`?

Ideally, I would like to use the `as.xts()` method - in particular here's the code I used to convert a data table to an `xts` object:

```
OrderBookxts <- as.xts.data.table(OrderBook, name= NULL)
```

I tried following Tushar's suggestion below by editing the code to the following line:

```
OrderBookxts <- as.xts.data.table(OrderBook, stocknames=STOCK)
```

but I get this warning:

`Warning message: 
In as.xts.data.table(OrderBook, stock = StockNames) : 
Following columns are not numeric and will be omitted: StockNames, Date`

So now I'm not really sure what to do :/ Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `xts` objects are time indexed matrices. So they need to have a time column, with a matrix, which by definition will have all other columns of same data type. So, if you want to store the `names` you can do it as an attribute of the `xts` object. 
`xts_obj<-xts(x=some_mat,order_by=TIME, stockname=STOCK)` . I am not sure if this solves your problem? Do you want to do any processing by the name of  `STOCK`?

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for the reply! I see, just one quick question but is `stockname` part of the general `xts` function? On the documentation page: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xts/versions/0.10-0/topics/xts they don't list `stockname` as an argument so I was wondering how it works. No, I don't want to do any processing by the name of the stocks but I want to be able to keep track of all the orders and trades (since there are over 200 different stocks there) so I want to make sure I know what trade belongs to a particular stock

Comment: No, not at all. You could name the attribute anything that suits you. In your scenario, I named the attribute as `stockname`. It's stored as a list. You will be able to see it using the `str` function.

Comment: @Tushar Ah I see, I have one last (and rather general) question: Could I expect my code to slow down if I create a 'Stockname' attribute? Since `xts` works best (and very quickly) with numeric data, since I'm going to be keeping the names of the stock in the `xts` object (which are character/string values) then could I expect the code to compile slower than before?

Comment: You said you are not using the names of the stock for any processing. So, that should not affect anything on the processing side. All it does is make your object take a little more memory.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks heaps :)

Comment: @Tushar I've just been trying it out now, and I was just wondering whether there is a way to do this using the `as.xts()` method rather than the `xts()` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151326/discussion-between-tushar-and-reallybadstatdude).

Comment: @Tushar Sorry for bothering you, if you have some time could you look at the code I wrote up?

Comment: can you share the output of `str(OrderBook)`?

Comment: @Tushar Sure, I put it into the chat since it can't fit in the textbox here :) Thanks heaps